# Referencing lists in list in NetLogo

Tags: list, netlogo

So, I have a list of lists. Kinda like that:

```
set plist [(list patch-at 0 0 100) (list patch-at 20 20 70) ...]
```

So the resulting list is a list of pairs *"patch, number"*. What I need to do is to do a **foreach** on that *plist*, and for each list in that list, I want to decrement the number, lets say in *"go"* function. So every tick, I want the number to be 1 less.

I failed to think of a way to get to that number. There is a code I have in *go*, *ask turtles [ ]*:

```
  foreach listp [
    set item 1 ??? item 1 ??? - 1
    if item 1 ??? <= 0 [remove ??? listp]
  ]
```

Where *???* is for the name of list i don't know (the nested lists). Obviously what I am trying to do is remove the patch from the list after 100 ticks.

Is there a way to reference those lists, or a way to somehow call *"set item 1"* without specifying the name of the list?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
turtles-own [plist]

to setup  ;;create an initialize some turtles
  ask n-of 10 patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set plist (list (list patch-at 0 0 100) (list patch-at 20 20 70))
    ]
  ]
end

to go  ;;update the `plist` of each turtles
  ask turtles [
    set plist map [list first ? (last ? - 1)] plist
    set plist filter [last ? > 0] plist
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, the key was the '?' symbol that I did not know about. Makes much more sense now.